# How to convert long form to wide form based on category in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following data.

```
   name     x1    x2    x3    x4
 1 V1_3  1     0     999     999
 2 V2_3  1.12  0.044  25.4     0
 3 V3_3  0.917 0.045  20.4     0
 4 V1_15 1     0     999     999
 5 V2_15 1.07  0.036  29.8     0
 6 V3_15 0.867 0.039  22.5     0
 7 V1_25 1     0     999     999
 8 V2_25 1.07  0.034  31.1     0
 9 V3_25 0.917 0.037  24.6     0
10 V1_35 1     0     999     999
11 V2_35 1.05  0.034  31.2     0
12 V3_35 0.994 0.037  26.6     0
13 V1_47 1     0     999     999
14 V2_47 1.03  0.031  33.6     0
15 V3_47 0.937 0.034  27.4     0
16 V1_57 1     0     999     999
17 V2_57 1.13  0.036  31.9     0
18 V3_57 1.03  0.037  28.1     0
```

I want to convert this data to the following data. Can someone give me some suggestion, please?

```
  name  est_3 est_15 est_25 est_35 est_47 est_57
1 V2    1.12   1.07   1.07   1.05   1.03    1.13
2 V3    0.917  0.867  0.917  0.994  0.937   1.03
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach for you. Your data is called `mydf` here. First, you want to choose necessary columns (i.e., `name` and `x1`) using `select()`. Then, you want to subset rows using `filter()`. You want to grab rows that begin with `V2` or `V3` in strings. `grepl()` checks if each string has the pattern. Then, you want to split the column, `name` and create two columns (i.e., `name` and `est`). Finally, you want to convert the data to a long-format data using `pivot_wider()`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

select(mydf, name:x1) %>%            
filter(grepl(x = name, pattern = "^V[2|3]")) %>% 
separate(col = name, into = c("name", "est"), sep = "_") %>%
pivot_wider(names_from = "est",values_from = "x1", names_prefix = "est_")

#  name  est_3 est_15 est_25 est_35 est_47 est_57
#  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 V2    1.12   1.07   1.07   1.05   1.03    1.13
#2 V3    0.917  0.867  0.917  0.994  0.937   1.03
```

For your reference, when you ask questions, you want to provide a minimal sample data and code. If you can do that, SO users can easily help you out. Please read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

**DATA**

```
mydf <- structure(list(name = c("V1_3", "V2_3", "V3_3", "V1_15", "V2_15", 
"V3_15", "V1_25", "V2_25", "V3_25", "V1_35", "V2_35", "V3_35", 
"V1_47", "V2_47", "V3_47", "V1_57", "V2_57", "V3_57"), x1 = c(1, 
1.122, 0.917, 1, 1.069, 0.867, 1, 1.066, 0.917, 1, 1.048, 0.994, 
1, 1.03, 0.937, 1, 1.133, 1.032), x2 = c(0, 0.044, 0.045, 0, 
0.036, 0.039, 0, 0.034, 0.037, 0, 0.034, 0.037, 0, 0.031, 0.034, 
0, 0.036, 0.037), x3 = c(999, 25.446, 20.385, 999, 29.751, 22.478, 
999, 31.134, 24.565, 999, 31.18, 26.587, 999, 33.637, 27.405, 
999, 31.883, 28.081), x4 = c(999, 0, 0, 999, 0, 0, 999, 0, 0, 
999, 0, 0, 999, 0, 0, 999, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```